# Recursion function to count how many times a certain sequence appears

Tags: python, function, if-statement, recursion, methods

I am writing a recursive function that takes an integer as input and it will return the number of times 123 appears in the integer.

So for example:

print(onetwothree(123123999123))

Will print out 3 because the sequence 123 appears 3 times in the number I entered into the function.

Here is my code so far:

```
def onetwothree(x):
    count = 0
    while(x > 0):
        x = x//10
        count = count + 1
    if (count < 3):  #here i check if the digits is less than 3, it can't have the sequence 123 if it doesn't have 3 digits
        return 0
    if (x%10==1 and x//10%10 == 2 and x//10//10%10==3):
        counter += 1
    else:
        return(onetwothree(x//10))
```

This keeps printing "0".

Comment: It keeps printing `0` because your while loop sets `x` to `0`, then calls `onetwothree(0)`, which is of course `0`.

Comment: @MarkSnyder so I remove that section then it says max output recursion exceeded.

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. Use pencil and paper (or debugger of your IDE) to go line-by-line and see what it actually does.

Comment: Do you understand that `x = x//10` actually changes the value of `x`?

Comment: @PM77-1 it checks if first digit is 1 then second digit is 2 then second digit is 3 and if it is add one to the counter then put the new number back through the function.

Comment: @PM77-1 yea i got rid of it but then i get "maximum recursion error"

Comment: Bottom line: you need to **understand** what your code is doing.  You cannot just arbitrarily remove its parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking recursion. A solution like so should work:

```py
def onetwothree(n, count=0):
    if n <= 0:
        return count

    last_three_digits = n % 1000
    n_without_last_number = n // 10

    if last_three_digits == 123:
        return onetwothree(n_without_last_number, count + 1)
    else:
        return onetwothree(n_without_last_number, count)

print(onetwothree(123123999123))
```

Outputs:

```
3
```

Comment: Of course. Make sure you understand how the solution above works. It's rather quite simple, but as I said, I think you were overthinking how to do this problem recursively. Unsure why the -1 on the response.

Comment: I should also add that this solution *does not* fit all edge cases. Input a negative number and you'll see it does not return your expected count. Perhaps that's something you can think of to add ;)

Comment: absolutley I wish u the best bro. thank you 1000x u helped me a lot

Comment: Not a problem -- and one last note, do keep in mind `//` is int division, where `/` is not -- important to remember.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many times '123' occurs in a number, why not convert your number from an integer to a string and use `str.count`?

Then your function would look like this:

```
def onetwothree(x):
    return str(x).count('123')
```

But it would also not be recursive anymore.

You could also just use the line `print(str(123123999123).count('123'))` which is pretty much the same as using it with the `onetwothree` function.

I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: @FreelanceVideoandPhotoEdit there's no place for the recursion here.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I'm misunderstanding something here, but I agree with @lenik, I don't see any place for recursion here.

Comment: @lenik not this solution, I want a recursive solution to my problem. ik this solution can't be recursive

Comment: @lenik awesome, could be a little more rude yea?